# How do I append to a compiled regex in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm writing functions to generate regular expressions to match various error messages.  For example...

```
sub more_than_one_slurpy_error {
    return qr{^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter }ms;
}
```

Then I can use them for testing to make it easier to deal with small changes in error messages.

```
eval q[ method two_array_params ($a, @b, @c) {} ];
like $@, more_than_one_slurpy_error;
```

I would like to optionally allow the user to pass in the file and line number they expect the error to come from.

```
eval q[ method two_array_params ($a, @b, @c) {} ];
like $@, more_than_one_slurpy_error(__FILE__, __LINE__-1);
```

I would write something like...

```
sub more_than_one_slurpy_error {
    my($file, $line) = @_;
    return _add_context(
        qr{^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter }ms,
        $file, $line
    );
}
```

The end result would be `qr{^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter at \Q$file\E line \Q$line\E\.$}ms`.

What would `_add_context` look like?  How do I append to a compiled regex, or accomplish this using a better method?

Comment: Maybe build the regex string and when you have everything you need, only then create the regex object ? Would this work ?

Comment: btw, `caller` could provide default values for `$file` and `$line`.

Comment: @ikegami I thought about that.  It places too many assumptions on the error message being checked.  It won't always be `__LINE__-1` nor even `__FILE__`.

Comment: I did say they'd be *defaults*, meaning you'd only use `caller` when the file and line weren't provided.

Comment: @ikegami They'd be wrong more often than they're right, which makes poor defaults.  In most cases I'd want to leave them off entirely... which says something about the current quality of the error messages.  One could make an argument for a file default to ensure the error at least got the right stack frame.  Anyhow, by putting it in a function rather than inlining the regexes I can add this feature later when the error quality improves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to add to a compiled pattern without recompiling the entire new pattern. Even `/^$re$/` and `qr/^$re$/` needs to recompile the entire pattern (although `/$re/` doesn't). But if it'll ever be possible to extend already compiled patterns, surely `/^$re$/` and `qr/^$re$/` will do that. So that's your best option.

```
sub _add_context {
    my ($re, $file, $line) = @_;
    return qr/${re}at \Q$file\E line \Q$line\E\.$/m;
}
```

But should `/m` always be specified? What if you want the presence or absence of `/m` from `$re` to apply to the extended pattern? For that, you can use the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use re qw( is_regexp regexp_pattern );

sub _add_context {
    my ($re, $file, $line) = @_;
    my $context_pat = "at \Q$file\E line \Q$line\E\\.\$";

    return $re . $context_pat
        if !is_regexp($re);

    my ($pat, $mods) = regexp_pattern($re);
    my $context_mods = $mods =~ /m/ ? 'm' : '';
    $re = eval('qr/$pat(?^$context_mods:$context_pat)/'.$mods)
        or die($@);

    return $re;
}

#line 1
say _add_context(qr{^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter }ms, __FILE__, __LINE__);
say _add_context(qr{^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter }s,  __FILE__, __LINE__);
say _add_context(qr{^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter }is, __FILE__, __LINE__);
say _add_context(  "^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter ",   __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Output:

```
(?^ms:^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter (?^m:at a\.pl line 1\.$))
(?^s:^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter (?^:at a\.pl line 2\.$))
(?^si:^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter (?^:at a\.pl line 3\.$))
^Cannot have more than one slurpy parameter at a\.pl line 4\.$
```

Comment: Thanks, `qr[${re} ...]` is what I went with.  It felt yicky and I supposed there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "\\\\FILE";
my $line = "50";

my $regex = _add_context(qr/^Something /ms,$file,$line);

sub _add_context {
    my ($reg, $file, $line) = @_;
    my $file_regex = quotemeta $file;
    my $line_regex = quotemeta $line;
    return qr/${reg}${file_regex}${line_regex}/;
}

my $string = <<'EOD';
test
Something \\FILE50
EOD

print $string . "\n";
print $regex . "\n";

if ( $string =~ /$regex/ ) {
    print "Match\n";    
} else {
    print "No match\n"; 
}
```

It uses [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) and you can test it on [ideone](https://ideone.com/1wP5J2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I considered that approach.  I like to avoid solutions based on escaping because it doesn't nest well.  BTW quotemeta can be done inline with `\Q$file\E`.